# 301 Redirect from one subdirectory to another

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a site that is a static html but has a wordpress blog. The wordpress subdirectory was called 'wordpress' so all blog posts would look like domain.com/wordpress/posttitle. This looked silly so we renamed the subdirectory 'news.'

I have tried using 301 redirects in the .htaccess file but doesn't seem to work. I need any/all blog posts with /wordpress/postitle to redirect to /news/posttitle/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect with a 301 all the URLs that start with `/wordpress` to `/news` appending the rest of the URL.